# GCP SDK changing cloud directories from local terminal

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, terminal, cloud, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/deploying-web-service). It seems that if I open a "cloud shell" in the browser, I can execute commands such as `cd <cloud path>` without any issues. However, when I try to do so from my laptop terminal I run into issues:

```
(base) user ~ % gsutil ls
gs://my_project/

(base) user ~ % cd gs://my_project/
cd: no such file or directory: gs://my_project/

(base) user ~ % gsutil cd gs://my_project/
CommandException: Invalid command "cd".

(base) user ~ % gcloud cd gs://my_project/
ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'cd'.
```

How should one change cloud directories from a local terminal, using gcloud SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program `gsutil` does not support the concept of a `current working directory`. Objects are specified using the full path `<protocol><bucket><object-name>`.

If you install the package `gcsfuse`, you can mount a Google Cloud Storage bucket as a directory. Then you can use the Linux shell command `cd` to move around the bucket as a file system.

[Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse)

This article shows how to set up gcsfuse on Cloud Shell:

[Unlimited persistent disk in google cloud shell](https://robertsahlin.com/unlimited-persistent-disk-in-google-cloud-shell/)